# How to convert mbox into csv format using python?

Tags: python, csv, email, mbox

I am writing to convert email Mbox format into CSV using Python 3

```
import mailbox
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open(r"...\clean_mail.csv", "w"))
for message in mailbox.mbox(r'...\Inbox-001.mbox'):
    if message.is_multipart():
        content = ''.join(part.get_payload() for part in message.get_payload())
    else:
        content = message.get_payload()
    writer.writerow([message['subject'],message['from'], message['date'], content])
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b7e7d65c9723> in <module>
      4 for message in mailbox.mbox(r'C:\Users\nikip\Documents\2021\Interview Preparation\sentiment analysis\Inbox-001.mbox'):
      5     if message.is_multipart():
----> 6         content = ''.join(part.get_payload() for part in message.get_payload())
      7     else:
      8         content = message.get_payload()
```

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Does the error occur with all mbox files you have tested?

Comment: I have been trying different codes to convert my takeout mbox into csv. If I download only subjects, from and to address then the code is running perfectly. But I need to have my content as well in the csv

Comment: Are you able to post a link to the mbox file? Your script should work for most cases. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: It's my own inbox file downloaded from google takeout. I need to convert the body of the email as well. But it throws this error. Downloading the date, subject, from and to works fine

Comment: If you could post a link to an mbox file which recreates your error (even if it just has a couple of entries), I would be able to test it with your script. My mbox file works fine. I will assume you are using a recent Python 3.x version.